# Meteor.js getting killed with no logs

Tags: node.js, meteor

Trying to run examples for Meteor.js.
It is failing with 'parties' example leaving no logs:

`$ meteor run`

`[[[[[ ~/parties ]]]]]`

`=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/`

`Killed`

Looks like it is crashing for some reason, but how to debug this?

`meteor reset` couldn't help.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the [linux out of memory killer](http://seriousbirder.com/blogs/linux-out-of-memory-oom-killer/) killing your process when the available memory is exhausted. Check your `ulimit` settings and make sure your node process has sufficient memory available to run the example.

Comment: While annoying, if you're running on a relatively small VM (ie: 500mb RAM), you can get by if you setup swap. I found occasionally meteor consumed 600mb during updates, etc... which is nuts. Anyways, good article here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks Peter Lyons, and especially @WesJohnson for posting a good solution. I set up 5GB swap following the link you posted and works perfectly now.