# meteor not running in my ubuntu

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I installed ubuntu on my laptop to work with meteor, but meteor is not working.

I downloaded from the official site:

```
 > curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4504    0  4504    0     0   1659      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  1658Removing your existing Meteor installation.
100  4504    0  4504    0     0   1539      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  1539
Downloading Meteor distribution
######################################################################## 100.0%

Meteor 0.9.3 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.

To get started fast:

  $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
  $ cd ~/my_cool_app
  $ meteor

Or see the docs at:

  docs.meteor.com

PC:~$ cd work/buildpulse-cerebus/
PC:~/work/buildpulse-cerebus$ meteor
^C
PC:~/work/buildpulse-cerebus$ meteor update
^C
PC:~/work/buildpulse-cerebus$ sudo meteor
```

After installation I changed to my directory (existing meteor app just cloned it) and when I run meteor nothing is happening.

If i create new meteor app it is running well, why is it not working with existing apps.

Comment: In this kind of post, it would be helpful to share the error log or stack trace so others can help you. You indicate the `meteor run` command works with new apps you create.  What is the error when running existing apps (and by that do you mean cloned meteor repos)?

Comment: @DavidKim I encountered very similar error and there was no error or logs - just a sudden "Killed" message. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Your process might be getting killed by Linux out of memory killer because available memory was exhausted. When I ran "meteor" or "meteor debug" on my new DigitalOcean Ubuntu (500Mb memory) machine it kept dying at "Downloading meteor-tool" with a "Killed" message. No logs, no error messages.

I finally read somewhere that meteor might be needing more memory that I had.

So the solution at this point is to allocate swapspace from harddisk to be used as additional memory or pay more $$$ to Digital Ocean for a machine with larger memory.

I went with the first option and allocated 5GB of swapspace memory from HDD [following this excellent article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04), and Meteor works fine now. I also learnt a little bit more about System Admin stuff.

[Here's the original stack-overflow answer that helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460358/meteor-js-getting-killed-with-no-logs)

Answer (score -1):

You may have forgotten to copy the hidden `.meteor` directory.

If you copied your apps from where they were originally created it is possible to see the behaviour you're describing.

To fix it just copy the app with the hidden `.meteor` directory.